# How do I change the value in <p id=[value] in html

Tags: html, select, onchange

I've asked a version of this question before and am very grateful for the help I've got but I'm still stuck so I thought it better to ask a refined question which now gets to the nub.

I've got the code below. The idea is that the `select` command should choose a value (initially XA, but could be XB, XC, XD) which will then be substituted for XA in the opening <span line and cause the appropriate `document.getElementById` line at the end to write.

But it doesn't work as it stands. Can anyone tell me how to correct it.

```html
<span id="XA">Change</span>
<P>

  <select class="selector" onchange="document.querySelector('p').id=this.value; console.log(document.querySelector('p').id)">
    <option value="XA" selected>XA</option>
    <option value="XB">XB</option>
    <option value="XC">XC</option>
    <option value="XD">XD</option>
  </select>

  <p id="XA"></p>
  <p id="XB"></p>
  <p id="XC"></p>
  <p id="XD"></p>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("XA").innerHTML = "Option is XA";
    document.getElementById("XB").innerHTML = "Option is XB";
    document.getElementById("XC").innerHTML = "Option is XC";
    document.getElementById("XD").innerHTML = "Option is XD";
  </script>
```

Comment: are you wanting to just change the initial span text or add the text to the paragraphs too?

Comment: I just want the opening <span statement (which currently has XA) to act as if it had contained XB (or XC, or XD) depending on what I select.

Answer (score 1):

First I would fix your html and make sure your ids are unique then you can do the following

```js
const span = document.getElementById('text');

document.querySelector('.selector')
  .addEventListener('change', event => {
    const thisValue = event.currentTarget.value;         // get current value
    const text = `Option is ${thisValue}`;
    span.innerText = text;                               // change span text
    document.getElementById(thisValue).innerText = text; // change p value
});
```

```html
<span id="text">Change</span>

<select class="selector">
  <option value="XA" selected>XA</option>
  <option value="XB">XB</option>
  <option value="XC">XC</option>
  <option value="XD">XD</option>
</select>

<p id="XA"></p>
<p id="XB"></p>
<p id="XC"></p>
<p id="XD"></p>
```